# How can I properly test DateTime in my service?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, phpunit

I am having difficulties on how to test my service properly, as it uses DateTime.

From what I have read, everything I need to do is to "isolate" the "collaborator" and a good way to accomplish that is pretty much injecting it. So far so good.

I will try to use a simple example, nothing fancy, just really easy one. Let's calculate the age.

1. Create a test for Age
2. Write a class and make it pass

```
public static function testAge(): void
{
    $bornAt = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat(
        'Y-m-d H:i:s',
        '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
    );

    $age = new Age();

    self::assertEquals(23, $age->calculate($bornAt));
}

class Age
{
    public function calculate(DateTimeImmutable $bornAt): int
    {
        $now = new DateTimeImmutable();

        return $bornAt->diff($now)->y;
    }
}
```

But what about my service that uses `Age`? This one is more coupled...

```
class CustomerAgeCalculation
{
    public function __construct(private Age $age)
    {
    }

    public function calculate(): int
    {
        // some logic here
        // some logic here
        // some logic here
        // some logic here

        $now = new DateTimeImmutable();

        $customerBornAt = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat(
            'Y-m-d H:i:s',
            '1999-01-01 00:00:00'
        );

        return $this->age->calculate($now, $customerBornAt);
    }
}
```

Yes, I could decoupled it by once again inject the variables. Even if I inject once again the collaborators I need into `CustomerAgeCalculation`, at some point in my application I will need to test it... but here comes my difficult...

How can I properly test a looong change that uses `Age` and make sure they are all working? For example:

```
`MyCustomClass01`
└──`MyCustomClass02`
   └──`MyCustomClass03`
      └──`MyCustomClass04`
         └──`MyCustomClass05`
            └──`MyCustomClass06`
               └──`CustomerAgeCalculation`
                  └──`Age`
```

Am I going to pass allllll the way down the parameters to Age?

Greatly appreciate your help. Thank you so much for your time.

Tried to test my service and I'm willing understand the best way possible to accomplish it.

Comment: Testing the pure function and it's result is called a function test. Testing two or more dependent classes together is called a integration test. You should rename the test to say what it does, like `testAgeCalculation()`. To test with multiple different values, go for a data-provider.

Comment: For `CustomerAgeCalculation` you simply can do the same as for the function test. Use a data provider for some examples and expectations.